# Размеры окна приложения

Tags: wpf, c#

При запуске wpf приложения требуется устанавливать размеры его окна согласно разрешению экрана пользователя. Подскажите как получить информацию о разрешении экрана в моем приложении?

Comment: Не знаком с WPF, но не проще ли указать атрибут— полноэкранное приложение? 

Comment: Нет, требуется именно определенный процент от экрана(по ширине и высоте).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

А после функции Initialize (если правильно помню) уже задать окну новый размер

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {        
     double _height =  SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
     double _width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;         
     MessageBox.Show("Разрешение экрана: " + _width.ToString() + " X "+_height.ToString());
    }
```